# How to pull unique child types and attributes from parent classes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

***Description of scenario:***

I have a parent class in c# called "**Employee"** from which several child classes inherit from. For example, "Part-time", "Full-Time", and others inherit from "Employee".

All employees in a certain division are payed a base wage, say $300. If they are full-time, they are payed the base wage of $300 plus the full time bonus of $200.

We have numerous classes of employees all of which recieve the base credit of $300 plus unique bonuses depending on their category.

***Question needing help with:***

I am trying to write a C# to SQL routine that increments everyone in that division the weekly credit of $300 plus the unique bonus of their category. I have several routines already that returns monthly lists of employees and their standing accounts with the company.
Is there any way to pull unique categories only?

```
dbo.PaymentRoutine
(@EmployeeClassification VARCHAR(50), @WeeklyPay DECIMAL(18,02))

UPDATE [Employee].Financial
set PaymentBalance += @UniqueBonus
```

How can I do this? I can manually type every category of workers we have in the code and run an increment... But I was hoping someone might be able to help me with a much less-newbie solution :)
Is there any way to see which are the *unique* children of a list< parent class> and access the attributes from those children in a routine like this? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?Thanks in advance for any comments and for helping me learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason for doing this in C#, I think you should do all the work in SQL. You will need an EmployeeType and a Department table so your PaymentRoutine stored procedure can get UniqueBonus from the database without you having to mess with parameters. You can then use the information in those tables to get any lists or reports you need.

If you do need to do this in C#, you can declare virtual properties on your base class and override them in the child classes. You can then use Linq to query the collection of all employees...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ListCategories()
    {
        var staff = new List<Employee>();
        staff.Add(new InvestmentBanker {Name="Fred Goodwin", Department = "NW"});
        staff.Add(new InvestmentBanker {Name="Nick Leeson", Department = "Barings"});
        staff.Add(new Cleaner{ Name = "George Formby", Department="NW" });

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var e in staff)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format(
             "update Employee set PaymentBalance=PaymentBalance+{0}" + 
             " where Name='{1}'\r\n", 
             e.CategoryBonus, e.Name));                
        }

    }


}


public class Employee
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Category { get { return "Employee"; } }
    public virtual decimal CategoryBonus { get { return 0; } }
}
public class Cleaner:Employee
{
    public override string Category {get { return "Cleaner"; }}
    public override decimal CategoryBonus{get { return 0.01M; }}
}
public class InvestmentBanker:Employee
{
    public override string Category { get { return "Banker"; } }
    public override decimal CategoryBonus { get { return 999999999999999M; } }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a second to post and the comments!

Comment: HAH! Loved the George Formby gag there! ;) I wonder how many actually got that reference :3

Neat coding, wish I was good at it, lol.